# How to make quick sort recursive?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Currently I am trying to make a recursive quick sort. There are many different methods for quick sort but for my method, I have to take the first element of the array and always use the first element of the array as the pivot. Then I compare it to all the elements and get the total number of comparisons. Elements that are smaller than the array should be behind the pivot followed by those that are bigger. So it should be pivot|elements smaller than pivot|elements greater than pivot. After comparing all the pivots, you should take the last element of the side that is smaller than the pivot and swap it with the pivot at the front. Currently I am lost on the how to make it recursive as I do believe I have successfully written code for the first pass. I am stuck trying to make it recursive so that it will call multiple passes of itself and that they are split. It would be stupid for it to sort all of it again. Instead, it should split the array into two parts, and recurse through the side smaller than the original pivot and the side bigger than the original pivot. This is a test case, as I later have to use this algorithm on a data file of 10,000 numbers (which is why I used long long although now that I think about it, it probably is overkill).

Below is my code in C++:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    long long quicksort(long long arr[],long long leftbegin, long long rightend)
    {
        long long i = leftbegin + 1;
        long long pivot = arr[leftbegin];
        long long comparisons = 0;
        for(long long j = i; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] > pivot)
            {
                rightend++;
                comparisons ++;
            }
            if(arr[j] < pivot)
            {
                long long temp = 0;
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                comparisons ++;
                i = i+1;
            }
        }
        long long temp = 0;
        temp = arr[0];
        arr[0] = arr[i-1];
        arr[i-1] = temp;
    //    for(int x = 0; x< 8; x++)
    //    {
    //        if(arr[x+1] >= arr[x])
    //        {
    //    
    //        }
    //        else
    //        {
    //            quicksort(arr,0,i);
    //            quicksort(arr,i+1,(rightend + 0));
    //        }
    //    }
    //    
        return comparisons;
    }

    /* Driver program to test above functions */
    int main ()
    {
        long long arr[8]= {3,8,2,5,1,4,7,6};
        cout<<"the number of comparisons are "<<quicksort(arr,0,8)<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<"arr is "<<endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
        }

    }
```

If I deleted the comments and ran the code with the commented part, it gives me error at long long temp = 0;, it will say exec bad access, even though it is able to run successfully. I use a mac and Xcode if it matters.

Comment: Okay I will do that.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully I will be able to get it soon.

Comment: Heh, 10000 easily fits into a `short int`. You need at least 10 digits to exceed `long int`.

Comment: The first `for`-loop has a hardcoded `8` which should be `rightend` instead. The `rightend++` does not make sense. Why does the array become bigger? The `comparison++` is in the wrong place, even if `arr[j] == pivot)` you still made 2 comparisons but you say you did 0. Why are you [`swap`ing](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) `arr[0]` with `arr[i-1]`? There are too many bugs, the answer and your code would not have much in common, so you may as well look up an implementation on wikipedia or something.

Comment: Actually rightend should not be rightend++, I have changed that in my code. The reason for the swap is just because it is mandatory that I do it that way. It also makes sense, as otherwise how would the pivot be sorted if the pivot is always the first element. By doing the swap, I am swapping the first element with the last element smaller than it. Which changes it from pivot|less than pivot|greater than pivot. To less than pivot|pivot|greater to than pivot.

Comment: You show code for a purely recursive quicksort (with recursive calls commented out). Production strength quicksort may iterate over the biggest partition, recursing into non-bigger ones. You may be looking for a purely _iterative_ quicksort - if so, please let everybody know _just why_.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a C++ implementation of QuickSort using recursion:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int partition (int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high];    //taking the last element as pivot
    int i = (low - 1);
    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++)
    {
        // If current element is smaller than or
        // equal to pivot
        if (arr[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;
            swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(arr[i + 1], arr[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    quickSort(arr, 0, n-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short version that uses std::nth_element():

```
template <class ITR> void quick_sort(ITR b, ITR e) {
    if(e-b < 2) {
        return;
    }
    ITR m = b+(e-b)/2;
    std::nth_element(b, m, e);
    quick_sort(b,m);
    quick_sort(m,e);
}
```

It can be called with any random access iterator, e.g.,

```
std::vector<int> V = ....;
quick_sort(V.begin(), V.end());
```

Note: it is probably a little bit more costly that a standard quick sort, but it is interesting because the sorting criterion can be changed between the levels. This feature can be used for instance to organize multidimensional points data along a space filling curve (Hilbert sort), as done in the CGAL library [1]. Note: std::nth_element() is bugged in gcc 4.8.1 [2], but it is fixed in more recent versions.

[1] http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Spatial_sorting/index.html

[2] https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58800